# Executing spark sql inside Transform method

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am writing a spark application in which I need to execute spark sql inside map (Transformation method).
While transforming one dataset to another , I need to fetch more information from another table.
Is it possible and if yes how to do this(preferably in Java)
I already tried to have sparkSession inside Transformer class, but that's not working.

Spark version : 2.3.2

Update: I have parent and child relationship . I already created joined dataset(parent and child) and then while transforming this dataset , I need to fetch information about parent and child from some more tables. So either I joined multiple tables(inner queries,joins etc at first place) or if there is some way to query while doing transformation, which does not seems so be after reading more about spark and reply on this question?

Comment: You'll need to provide us with some concrete code so that we can help but in short the way to do it in Spark is to join two dataset and then process them: you don't retrieve a dataset inside a transformation method, you build a dataset of all the data you'll need and join.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually I got solution. Rather than fetching information inside transformation method(which seems very hard or impossible), I created all required SQL joins in start itself and first I was hesitant to do many joins, but that worked out and quite fast for bigger dataset. So problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading few blogs and replies here , I realize rather than fetching information inside transformation method(which seems very hard or impossible, because that would be required spark-session etc),
I created all required SQL joins in first place itself(we made 4 joins in single sql query).
Initially I was hesitant to do many joins, but that worked out and quite fast for bigger data-set. So from our experience I can share that its good to join multiple tables if required.
Unfortunately I can't share code as it's kind of confidential.